# Reading HTML mail with PGP/Mime encryption in Thunderbird with Enigmail

Tags: gnupg, enigmail

Yesterday I asked how to [configure Thunderbird with Enigmail to use PGP/Mime](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73413/use-pgp-mime-with-thunderbird-and-enigmail) encryption for signing emails. This works, but I noticed one problem. I don't know if this is common to Thunderbird, or specific to my settings. When I send a PGP/Mime HTML mail to myself and open it in Thunderbird, I see the plaintext version. So HTML layout is gone. When I open this mail on my phone with K-9 Mail, I see the layout.

**How can I get Thunderbird to display the HTML version?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PGP/MIME generates a multi-part MIME message with a plain text part, an HTML part, and a digital signature part.  You can verify by using "View -> Message source" and looking for the MIME separators.  (See below.)

In Thunderbird, with the message open, click "View -> Message body as" and select "Original HTML."  It looks like Thunderbird digitally signs the plain text part of the message, and then displays that by default

Just in case "MIME separators" doesn't make sense, you're looking for something like this:

```
--------------080906000108090307010501--

--1q66lbherk2Rpaa3MLxXVJ9NM8q4ix8Gs
Content-Type: application/pgp-signature; name="signature.asc"
Content-Description: OpenPGP digital signature
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="signature.asc"

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (MingW32)
```